# How to avoid text-spacing after inserting figure?

Tags: spacing, graphics

I am trying to insert a little figure(logo) to a document without changing the vertical spacing.

I have two lines of text and I want to insert the figure in the align with the second line. I can do that simply with the code snippet:

```
{\bf The First Line }\\{\bf The Second Line} \hfill\includegraphics[height=24pt]{google}
```

After that, spacing between text changes according to the vertical size of the figure. I wish to have the same spacing after including the figure too.

How can I do that?

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note `\bf` is a deprecated command not defined at all in the core LaTeX format (but added for compatibility reasons by some classes). `\textbf{The First Line}` would be better markup.

If you want the line never to be opened up even if the figure would overprint the line above then `\smash{\includegraphics[height=24pt]{google}}`  The `\smash` command hides the height of its argument.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a bottom aligned `tabular`:

```
\noindent{\bfseries
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  First line\\
  Second line
\end{tabular}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=24pt]{google}
```

[image]